# roslaunch error , rplidar

Tags: ros, roslaunch, rplidar, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From this part, I have several error.

When I input this,

```
 $ roslaunch rplidar_ros rplidar.launch
```

it shows

```
[rplidar.launch] is neither a launch file in package [rplidar_ros] nor is [rplidar_ros] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

However, if I input

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$ source /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch rplidar_ros rplidar.launch
... logging to /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/687ff54e-e312-11e6-a5f7-0022cffa2d4b/roslaunch-ubuntu-7014.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://ubuntu:54487/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.20
 * /rplidarNode/angle_compensate: True
 * /rplidarNode/frame_id: laser
 * /rplidarNode/inverted: False
 * /rplidarNode/serial_baudrate: 115200
 * /rplidarNode/serial_port: /dev/ttyUSB0

NODES
  /
    rplidarNode (rplidar_ros/rplidarNode)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[rplidarNode-1]: started with pid [7032]
RPLIDAR running on ROS package rplidar_ros
SDK Version: 1.5.7
Error, cannot bind to the specified serial port /dev/ttyUSB0.
[rplidarNode-1] process has died [pid 7032, exit code 255, cmd /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rplidar_ros/rplidarNode __name:=rplidarNode __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/687ff54e-e312-11e6-a5f7-0022cffa2d4b/rplidarNode-1.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/687ff54e-e312-11e6-a5f7-0022cffa2d4b/rplidarNode-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253196/roslaunch-error-,-rplidar/) by [sophie.shin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29160/sophie.shin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
>  $ roslaunch rplidar_ros rplidar.launch
> ```

> it shows

> ```
> [rplidar.launch] is neither a launch file in package [rplidar_ros] nor is [rplidar_ros] a launch file name
> ```

```
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

This is completely expected: you appear to not have `source`d the correct `setup.bash` file from the workspace that contains the `rpilidar_ros` package. Without the information from the `setup.bash`, ROS cannot find that package, hence the error message.

And I'm slightly confused, as you seem to know that already, seeing as you `source /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` two lines later.

> However, if I input

> ```
> ubuntu@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$ source /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
> ubuntu@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch rplidar_ros rplidar.launch
> ```

```
... logging to /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/687ff54e-e312-11e6-a5f7-0022cffa2d4b/roslaunch-ubuntu-7014.log
[..]
process[rplidarNode-1]: started with pid [7032]
RPLIDAR running on ROS package rplidar_ros
SDK Version: 1.5.7
Error, cannot bind to the specified serial port /dev/ttyUSB0.
[rplidarNode-1] process has died [pid 7032, exit code 255, cmd /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rplidar_ros/rplidarNode __name:=rplidarNode __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/687ff54e-e312-11e6-a5f7-0022cffa2d4b/rplidarNode-1.log].
[..]
```

This looks like a problem with the serial port that you are telling `rpilidar_ros` to use.

Are you sure that you have a `ttyUSB0`, and that the lidar is connected to that port? Have you also made sure your user `ubuntu` has read and write access to the serial port?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sophie.shin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29160/sophie.shin/) on 2017-01-29**:
Thank you for your comment.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-29**:
Do you have the `rpilidar` working now?

**Comment by [sophie.shin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29160/sophie.shin/) on 2017-01-29**:
Thank you for your reply.
I remove all and re-install and follow the installation guide step by step again.

There are various version regarding the USB port setting on the web post..
Finally I followed below,

```
$ ls /dev/ttyUSB*/
$ sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-29**:
The `sudo chmod 666 ..` will not be permanent. I'd advise you to look into `udev` rules.

**Comment by [razgrin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29866/razgrin/) on 2017-03-29**:
hey gvdhoorn, I have the same issue here, and I wanted to know what the permanent fix would be? (I'm really new at this, so I'm still trying to learn all the basic terminology, please go easy on me)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-30**:
As I wrote in my earlier comment: look into creating some suitable `udev` rules. Search for `ros udev` and you'll probably find some examples.